# How to combine payment method and order review tab in a single tab

Tags: onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout, checkout-page

Can anyone help me to solve the requirement in magento 1.9
In the checkout page how do I combine the payment method tab and order review tab in a single tab .

Thanks .